# In angular formly, how to add ng-click or ng-change to a checkbox?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am using angular-formly, I am trying to add the normal angular events to a checkbox but no joy. Here is what I have:

```
{
    type: "checkbox",
    key: "is_active",
    templateOptions: {
        type: "",
        label: "Is Active"
    }
}
```

I looked over the documentations over and over and I can not find the solution. Please show where to add ng-click or ng-change in the above.

I hoped something like the below would work:

```
{
    type: "checkbox",
    key: "is_active",
    templateOptions: {
        type: "",
        label: "Is Active"
    },
    ngClick : "functionName"
}
```

where `functionName` is a function inside the controller that renders the form. So my functions will always be in my controller, I just need to define or pass the event to the checkbox

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the definition for type 'checkbox' I have is the default one the formly provides. So  I don't have a type definition to tie this functionality to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been awhile since I've messed with formly but I believe this should do

```
{
    type: "checkbox",
    key: "is_active",
    templateOptions: {
        type: "",
        label: "Is Active",
        onClick: yourControllerFunctionHere  //notice this isn't a string but a reference to your controller function
    }        
}
```

This is referenced in the [ngModelAttrsTemplateManipulator documentation](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/ngmodelattrstemplatemanipulator).  I love formly but the documentation is hard to navigate

Comment: If onClick doesn't work, [onChange should](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

use *ngModelElAttrs* attribute:

```
{
    type: "checkbox",
    key: "is_active",
    templateOptions: {
      label: "Is Active"
    },
    ngModelElAttrs: {
      'ng-change': "model.text = 'asdf'"
    }
  }
```

in this fiddle (http://jsbin.com/xavitufudu/1/edit?js,output) I added your checkbox as a first field, which on change changes next field's content.

this approach does not have direct access to outer scope, but rather to formly's scope. In order to reach an outer scope we can add field's controller, which may access outer scope (variable functions):

```
{
    type: "checkbox",
    key: "is_active",
    templateOptions: {
      label: "Is Active"
    },
    ngModelElAttrs: {
      'ng-change': "myFunc()"
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.myFunc = function () {
        vm.model.text = 'Another text';
      };
    }
  }
```

here, we access `vm.model.text` via outer scope (although we could also access it via inner field's scope as `$scope.model.text`)

Comment: with this approach i am unable to pass a function

Comment: we can call outer controller's functions via inner field's controller, see my answer update